# Calendarserver 3.2+ on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, webserver, calendar, webdav

I am looking to install calendarserver (at least version 3.2) on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS box. The box is a 64-bit box, and the 64-bit version of Ubuntu is installed. Can this be done, and if so, what is the easiest (and safest) way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find 3.2 in the [official repositories for 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&searchon=names&keywords=calendarserver) and also no PPA on Launchpad. It seems that you need to install the latest non-LTS release (version 3.2 is in 12.10 and onward, but you don't want to upgrade through all non-LTS releases later) or at least the corresponding packages for calendarserver.

The safest way would be to wait for the 14.04 release.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know the next LTS release was coming out so soon. (The tentative release date is April 17, 2014.) I will just wait for that. Thanks!